# Bot that DM's chosen keywords to chosen users

Tags: message

What I'm looking to do is to create a bot that will be in a private channel only accessible to the admins. All users will have keywords that they have chosen prior and will get notified about. Lets say user 'x', has chosen "brown" as a keyword, when a comment comes into the private channel containing the keyword "brown", I want the bot to send that message, copy and pasted, directly to the user 'x' that chose that keyword. So basically I would like to know how to make a bot they has a keyword feature that copies that exact message and dm's that user that chose that keyword.

Is this possible, if so how would I go about it?
Thanks

Comment: This is an off-topic question. Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). :) In general what you ask can be achieved with different technologies. So you have to decide one before you ask and put in the tags of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the bots i have made, i have used python.
Selenium web-driver is fairly easy to use if you intend on scraping the data from `HTML` pages.

In any case, you could use `flask` and `mysql.connector` to create the user interface and login for control of the bot.

If there are any other things you want it to do, i'm sure there's a library out there to do it, or you could just launch some kind of macro or script on the server.

Be very careful of permissions and whatnot if you intend on allowing remote control of other scripts and data on the server though.